# toOptionArray getting empty array

Tags: category, getfilterable-attributes

I had stuck on one issue.this is my configuration filed from the system.xml

```
<topnav_laptop translate="label">
  <label>My Dropdown:</label> 
  <comment>Source model provider Magento's default Yes/No values</comment> 
  <frontend_type>Multiselect</frontend_type> 
  <sort_order>90</sort_order> 
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default> 
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website> 
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> 
  <source_model>Neo_Topnav_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Laptop</source_model> 
- <!-- <source_model>Neo_Career_Model_Career</source_model>
  --> 
  </topnav_laptop>
```

I have toOptionArray() with the following code at Laptop.php

```
public function toOptionArray(){
        $topnavi_model = new Neo_Topnav_Model_Topnavi();
        $navi_model = $topnavi_model->laptopdata();
        //$themes = $this->laptopdata();
        return $navi_model;
      }

public function getCatAttributes() {
        $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
        $r = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($r);
        $validAttributes = array();
        //print_r($layer->getFilterableAttributes()); exit;
        foreach ($layer->getFilterableAttributes() as $attribute) {
            //allow only select attributes - you can implement your additional filters here
            if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select'){
                $validAttributes[] = $attribute;
            }
        }
        //print_r($validAttributes); exit;    
        $result = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($validAttributes as $validAttribute){
            $result[$i]['value'] = $validAttribute['attribute_id'];
            $result[$i]['label'] = $validAttribute['attribute_code'];
            $i++;
        }
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
        return $result;
        //return $validAttributes;
    }

    public function laptopdata(){
            $lappa = array();
            $lapp = $this->getCatAttributes();
            $lappa = $lapp;
            return $lappa;
        }
```

In Neo_Topnav_Model_Topnavi model i have a function called laptopdata which returns array.but in the toOptionArray function i am getting empty array.where's when i am accessing the laptopdata() outside magento i am getting array.

Please Help me.

Comment: `toOptionArray()` should returns array from arrays with label and value -> `return array(array('label' => 'some_label', 'value' => 'some_value'));`. Is `laptopdata()` returns this?

Comment: yes laptopdata returns the array which toOptionArray need.i checked this function return data from outside the function.but not in the toOptionArray.

Comment: Try with `$topnavi_model = Mage::getModel('...');`. I don't know how you defined it in the config.xml. There should be no difference, but give it a try. Also paste the code from `Neo_Topnav_Model_Topnavi`.

Comment: check my code...

Comment: i called laptopdata() outside magento which is working.but in the toOptionArray() not working

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting value from your `latopdata()` function with outside of magento then you should have to prepare array like below

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $hlp = Mage::helper('yourmodule');
        return array(
            array('value' => 0, 'label' => $hlp->__('Just Url Key')),
            array('value' => 1, 'label' => $hlp->__('Current URL')),
            array('value' => 2, 'label' => $hlp->__('First Attribute Value')),
        );
    }
```

so it should be nested array with your `label` and `value` as above

or just try to add above array in your function and check what happen

**EDIT**

```
  public function laptopdata(){         
            $lapp = $this->getCatAttributes();
            $lappa = array($lapp);
            return $lappa;
        }
```

hope this will clear your logic

Comment: still empty array

Comment: please check your source model class and xml tag in `system.xml`

Comment: or try with yes/no value  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model> if its working then you have error in your source model tag

Comment: yesno i had checked and it is working. and when i add return array with hard code value it is working

Comment: that means you have issue in `$topnavi_model->laptopdata();` check with my sample function

Comment: @PradeepSanku, Pls dont forget to acpt and voteup. if my answer is useful to you.